# Ambiguous occurrence `take`

Tags: haskell

```
 Ambiguous occurrence `take'
It could refer to
   either `Prelude.take',
          imported from `Prelude' at src\Main.hs:1:8-11
          (and originally defined in `GHC.List')
       or `Data.Set.take',
          imported from `Data.Set' at src\Main.hs:4:1-15
          (and originally defined in `Data.Set.Internal')
       or `Data.Map.take',
          imported from `Data.Map' at src\Main.hs:3:1-15
          (and originally defined in `Data.Map.Internal')
            |
         36 | createMines g fst = Data.Set.fromList $ take mineCount $ shuffle g $
```

Please tell me how to fix this error.I use import Data.Map and import Data.Set

Comment: You better import Data.Map and Data.Set qualilfied or if you don't use `take` from Data.Map and Data.Set make you import with `hiding (take)`. Have a look at [import](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import).

Comment: What happened when you googled the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because you imported modules that export functions with the same name. If you then use such function (like `take`), the compiler does not know what function you aim to use.

You can make a [*qualified* import [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import), so:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
```

You can then use a function the `Data.Set` module with `S.take` for example. If you use `take`, it will use the one defined in the prelude.

Comment: Note there are two parts to this. The `qualified` means you *cannot* use anything from the module without prefixing it with the module name. The `as` gives you an alias for the module name. Each can be used independently of the other.